# Sharing a GNUCash file

Tags: gnucash

i'm trying to use the Accounts (.gnucash) file on another computer.  i just use FTP to copy it over.  When i open it up - it looks alright.  However when trying to use one or more Reports we have created, the Menu item comes up empty (Reports/Saved Report Configurations).  Since these are Linux machines, these user-created reports must be saved somewhere.  Does anyone know where?

Have a wonderful evening and please stay safe!  :)

Comment: This is probably more suitable for superuser.com, or maybe unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: See: [How to move data for GnuCash from one computer to another?](https://superuser.com/q/1642404/149731) and follow the link to: https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-guide/basics-migrate-settings.html#Report-loc

Comment: Thanks guys.  i'll check out the link.  Have a wonderful evening!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are few [Configuration Locations](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations) are used for reports:

- [USER_DATA_HOME](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations#https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations#USER_DATA_HOME) - saved reports stored here
- [GNC_DATA_HOME](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations#In_GNC_DATA_HOME) - saved report configurations and stylesheets
- [GNC_CONFIG_HOME](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Configuration_Locations#In_GNC_CONFIG_HOME) - may load additional reports